javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.validatiorExcption
I am building a java client to connect to impala database server and we have to use jks certificate to connect to their server.
I am using JdbcTemplate to make connection and setting the configurations in a DataSource, there I set the jks certificate. But I am getting this error while running the SQL query from that connection. It is not able to connect to server because it is not getting server path. I am setting the certificates this way
datasource.addConnectionPropert("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "certificatepath");

Error logs

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
sun.security.validator.validatiorExcption: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPatgBuilderException:unable to
find valid certificate path to requested target) exception stack is
org.apache commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
PoolableConnectionFactory(could not open client transport with JDBC
uri:)


Did you tried to follow documentation?

Internet says that you may specify path to keystore in connection string: impalaConnectionURL=jdbc:impala://mycluster.lan:21050/default;AuthMech=3;krbRealm=MYCOMPANY.COM;SSL=1;SSLKeyStore=/opt/cloudera/security/thekey.jks;SSLKeyStorePwd=correctpassword;UID=correctuser;PWD=correctpassword.
